# Creating a table/dataframe for one to many join

Tags: python, dataframe, join, arraylist

I am trying to write a function which does the following

def OneToMany(2):

that returns me a following table:

| Num | Join |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |

The function should work for any number in place of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood you correctly:

```py
def OneToMany(n):
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {"Num": i, "Join": j} for i in range(n, 0, -1) for j in range(i, -1, -1)
    )


print(OneToMany(2))
```

Prints:

```
   Num  Join
0    2     2
1    2     1
2    2     0
3    1     1
4    1     0
```

Comment: This totally works! Thanks a ton! Just for educational purpose - can you explain how this script works and the nested for loops you used to achieve this? My friend and I are just racking our brains over here trying to understand the logic behind this. Thanks!

Comment: @TejusArora Try debug the code by rewriting the comprehension `[{"Num": i, "Join": j} for i in range(n, 0, -1) for j in range(i, -1, -1)]` to separate lines. Basically, it creates list of dictionaries `[{"Num":xx, "Join":xx}, ...]` and pandas creates the dataframe from it.

Comment: Got it! I was just thrown off by the -1 STOP condition on the second for loop and realized the STOP condition isn't inclusive.  Thanks again!